# Outlook add a task

Tags: outlook, task

I need some help please. I have managed to create a task in outlook using VB and SendItem. My problem is the code I'm using is creating two tasks and not just the one I want.

I have tried removing the `.Save` as I thought this was the cause but it still adds two tasks. I have added breakpoints to the code to ensure its not cycling round twice for some obscure reason and it just executes once.

Would appreciate someone telling me the obvious please

Code snippet:

```
`If bNotFount = False Then
        Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set ItemT = GetCurrentItem()
        Set taskFolder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
        Set olTask = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks).Items.Add(olTaskItem)
        With olTask
            .Subject = ItemT.Subject
            .Attachments.Add ItemT
            .Body = ItemT.Body
            .DueDate = Now + 1
            .Move taskFolder
            .Save
            .Display 'show the task to add notes
        End With
    End If'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to move it to the default task folder because you saving it there anyway.
Just remove `.Move taskFolder` line.

I updated your code:

```
  Private Sub Application_ItemSend(Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend

    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim taskFldr As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    '    If bNotFount = False Then
      Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

      taskFldr = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks)
    olTask = taskFldr.Items.Add
      With olTask
      .Subject = Item.Subject
      .Attachments.Add(Item)
      .Body = Item.Body
      .DueDate = Now + 1
      .Save()
      .Display() 'show the task to add notes
      End With
    ' End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks very much. Worked a treat!

Comment: And if you ever use Move, keep in mind that it returns the new item. You must immediately discard the old object: olTask = olTask.Move(SomeFolder)